# PHP: escape filename as linux does

Tags: php, escaping, filenames

I'm having troubles with filenames upload by users which I have to process. When I try to access them, because some of them have special characters, the command used says the file is not found or similar.

I've used escapeshellcmd with no sucess.

When I use the "tab" key in linux console (when you have started to type the filename and you want it to complete), the bash escape the filename correctly, and if I use exactly that "escaped" filename, it works.

I've tried this:

```
preg_replace("/[^a-zA-Z0-9\-\.\s]/", "\\\\$0", $filename)
```

to escape everything except numbers, letters, - and spaces ... but I found that for file "test_1.jpg", this command converts it into "test_1.jpg", and it does not work, since "_" does NOT need to be converted.

I'm afraid there could be more "allowed" characters, so my question is ... how can i "clone" the escape function of "tab" key in linux console bash?

Comment: Why don't you rename the files on upload?

Comment: sorry but I cant see the difference between "test_1.jpg" and "test_1.jpg" ??

Answer (score 3):

If you want to use the file name as a shell command parameter you can use the function [escapeshellarg](http://php.net/manual/en/function.escapeshellarg.php).

Answer (score 1):

I use this for both file names and for making URLs out of blog post titles and the like.

```
// everything to lower and no spaces begin or end
$path = strtolower(trim($path));

// adding - for spaces and union characters
$find = array(' ', '&', '\r\n', '\n', '+',',');
$path = str_replace ($find, '-', $path);

//delete and replace rest of special chars
$find = array('/[^a-z0-9\-<>]/', '/[\-]+/', '/<[^>]*>/');
$repl = array('', '-', '');
$path = preg_replace ($find, $repl, $path);
```

Comment: sorry but i can NOT rename the file, I need the same file name untouched as the user uploads

Comment: Not renaming the file is not a secure approach. What if someone posted a file named `../../.htaccess` with a bunch of rules to defeat server security settings? Or wipe out a password file? Or supply a shell script as a php file in a public directory? It is vital to sanitize the file names. You *never* need or want to take whatever junk the user gives you at face value--if that is truly a constraint of the project then the constraints are fundamentally flawed.

Answer (score 0):

If you are accessing these files directly on your web server, your files names need to be url encoded with urlencode, not escapeshellcmd

Comment: You didn't understand me :P   I'm accesing that files through EXEC command since I need to do something with them "like console" ... the only thing I need is the TITLE of the QUESTION ... how to escape as linux does ... I think it escapes everything but a-z\.  but i'm not sure

Answer (score 0):

this is the function I put together, hope it helps

you can all add more by adding | with another escaped character

```
public function linuxFilename($file)
{
    //make the linux filename perfect
    return preg_replace("/ |'|\(|\)/", '\\\${0}', $file);
}
```