# file_exists() and file_get_contents() fail on a file which is named output‹ÕÍÕ¥.txt in PHP?

Tags: php, windows, encoding, utf-8, filesystems

`file_exists()` and `file_get_contents()` fail on a file which is named `output‹ÕÍÕ¥.txt` (as an example), although I know it exists?

I'm guessing its got something to do with the special characters within the file name?.

So was wondering whats a workaround?

Appreciate all responses.

FYI:

Please note, if your thinking why not simply change the file name? - I can't as the file name is generated generically, and to change the file name will be mean using PHP's file functions (which don't seem to allow special characters within the file name args - unless I've misinterpreted/misunderstood anything).

I'm using PHP 5.2 on Windows.

Comment: Did you have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4994119/php-escape-filename-as-linux-does ?

Comment: @sdolgy: There is no need to shell escape for file_exists and the like AFAIK.

Comment: @newbtophp: How do you get the file-name?

Answer (score 5):

Ensure that the encoding of the file-system is the same as the encoding of the string that contains the file-name in your PHP code.

Otherwise you're testing for the wrong file to exist.

For example, if your file-system does not support UTF-8 but the file-name is encoded in UTF-8.

**Edit:**

So you have commented that the filename is in UTF-8 and you're using windows.

That's exactly the point my answer was about. As [written here](http://en.jinzorahelp.com/wiki/Enable_UTF-8):

> Bad news for Windows Users: Windows filesystems (FAT, FAT32, NTFS) are not UTF-8 aware. Filenames are encoded in ISO-8859-1 or CP437/CP850/( or whatever suits your language) depending on filesystem and localisation. So you will probably get in trouble trying to match filenames from database to filesystem if you follow this guide. (Although I've never tried it.)
>
> Windows workaround: Modern windows versions support UTF-8 on mounted shares. Make a share of your mediafolder and mount it as a network drive.

So either make a share or encode the filename in the encoding that actually works with your filesystem. This is not a bug in PHP. You're just no checking for the right file-name, that's all.

**Edit2:**

Assuming you have NTFS which *might* accept UTF-16 (which is not really precise AFAIK, but you can give it a try), you could convert the UTF-8 filename into an UTF-16 fiĺename:

```
$name = mb_convert_encoding($name, 'UTF-16', 'UTF-8');
```

And then try if file_exists works. Keep in mind that his might not be technically correct, *and* you *might* have an additional encoding issue which prevents you from correct use even with this re-encoding.

**Related: [What encoding are filenames in NTFS stored as?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050973/what-encoding-are-filenames-in-ntfs-stored-as)**

Comment: Well according to mb_detect_encoding() the file-name is UTF-8...after some googling I came accross the following bug: https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=46990 ? so if thats the case then instead of using file-system functions directly could I use exec() (or alike) to rename the file to a file-name in which the file-system functions accept?

Comment: @newbtophp: Err, that's exactly the point: Your windows does not support UTF-8 file-names most obviously. And that's not a bug in PHP after all. You'll notice that, if you pass that over to the shell as well. Edited the question for more clarity. You need to take care yourself having the right file-name.