# fopen() fails to open file with arabic filename

Tags: php

I am having problems with reading html files in php.
When you try to open html file with Arabic name using fopen(), you get an error saying the file doesn't exist.
Is there any way to make this working?

Comment: Can you show what your doing and the name of the file?

Comment: What character encoding do you use when specifying the file’s location and what OS are you on?

Comment: possible duplicate of (now corrected) [file_exists() and file_get_contents() fail on a file which is named output‹ÕÍÕ¥.txt in PHP?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634832/file-exists-and-file-get-contents-fail-on-a-file-which-is-named-outputoio-t/6634924)

Comment: I'm working on Windows os, using apache server.

Comment: Your question looks really like a this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634832/file-exists-and-file-get-contents-fail-on-a-file-which-is-named-outputoio-t/6634924

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You most likely have conflict between the file system encoding and your application encoding, or some file permissions issue.

(just a guess, too few data to judge)