# PHP read correct file name with latin characters

Tags: php, character-encoding, filenames

I have some issues with file name encoding when extended latin characters are used. I have the following files:

```
Letter Ā.mp4
Letter A.mp4
```

In any way with different methods in PHP gives me the filenames as the same:

```
Letter A.mp4
Letter A.mp4
```

Even iterating over them this name is shown twice, it means that it sees 2 different files.

I tried to change script encoding with `mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8")`, tried [recursive directory iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php), tried [glob](http://php.net/manual/en/function.glob.php) etc. In no way I cant get PHP to output the full filename with `Ā`

What file listing method should I use to see those files with illegal names? I want to rename those files without bad characters.

Comment: What OS and filesystem are you using? It seems to work fine on Linux and ext4.

Comment: Windows server 2008 R2 x64 with huge NTFS for backups. Here is my phpinfo https://jsfiddle.net/jevcrgL1/embedded/result/ , server is not public.

Comment: Did you try to convert the output from utf16 to utf8? These questions might be related to your problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6634832/file-exists-and-file-get-contents-fail-on-a-file-which-is-named-output-%C3%95%C3%8D%C3%95%C2%A5?lq=1 http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2050973/what-encoding-are-filenames-in-ntfs-stored-as